vb.net get a string between a string, and continue to get a string add it to a listbox until the string in between the string is not found
maybe there is a much easier way however i am new to VStudio and used to OLD vb3 or 6, the new classes that are shared which we used to have to actually code all of them into a module and save the module, the fact that i can do application.path is absolutely stunning... maybe i am missing something
Public Function extractStr(source As String, start As String, ending As String)
        Return source.Substring(InStr(source, start, CompareMethod.Text) + start.Length - 1, InStr(source, ending) - (InStr(source, start, CompareMethod.Text) + start.Length))
End Function

and me calling that function in a button ...
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim tickr As String = extractStr(TxtScrape.Text, lblPreTickData1.Text, lblPreTickData2.Text)
    Dim LastSearchEnd As Integer = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    'Dim tickrperc As Decimal = extractStr(TxtScrape.Text, lblPreTickData1.Text, lblPreTickData2.Text)
    TickerPRE.Text = tickr
        MsgBox("found " & TickerPRE.Text)
End Sub

i am new to streamreader.... many things have changed for i have not coded in 20 years...  it keeps returning the same string rather then going to the next starting point or ending up in a different point...
i am sure it is probably as simple as changing the starting point to the ending point?
hopefully someone can help

Can you please rewrite that first paragraph so that it is in comprehensible English?

Are you parsing XML files? Because this isn't the way to do it.

You can use a Regular Expression (regex):
Dim documentText = "The (quick) brown (cow) jumps over (the) lazy dog"
Dim searchStart = "\(" 'need to escape the left bracket
Dim searchEnd = "\)" 'need to escape the right bracket
Dim regexPattern = "(?<=" & searchStart & ")\w*(?=" & searchEnd & ")"
Dim matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(documentText, regexPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
For Each match In matches
  Console.WriteLine(match)
Next
Console.WriteLine("--------")
Console.WriteLine("Finished")

If you aren't familiar with regex's here is a cheat sheet: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.php
And here is an online tester: https://regex101.com/
